# alignment of text between 2 lines in align*

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, align

I have this:

```
\begin{align*}  
&f(1) = -11 & &\mbox{while q satisfies} &q(1) = 11,\\  
&f(-2) = 20 & &\mbox{} &q(-1) = 20  
\end{align*}
```

which puts the text "while" on the same line as the first line (obviously). Is there a way to have it in the (vertical) middle of the two lines? I.e. in between the two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few possibilities. I included your original code. Note that the align environment isn't really required for this structure.

My first version simply adds a line to your original code and inserts the text in that line. It is not an appealing solution. The version I prefer is the second to last, which uses `cases`. If you don't like the braces, you may use the last version that uses `aligned`. You can replace `aligned` by `gathered` or an `array` (as Daniel's solution).

```
\begin{align*}
&f(1) = -11 & &\mbox{while q satisfies} &q(1) = 11,\\
&f(-2) = 20 & &\mbox{} &q(-1) = 20
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
&f(1) = -11 & &&q(1) = 11,\\
&&&\mbox{while q satisfies} \\
&f(-2) = 20 & &\mbox{} &q(-1) = 20
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}f(1) = -11\\f(-2)=20\end{cases}&&\text{while $q$ satisfies}&&\begin{cases}q(1) = 11\\q(-1)=20\end{cases}
\end{align*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}f(1) = -11\\f(-2)=20\end{cases}\qquad\text{while $q$ satisfies}\qquad\begin{cases}q(1) = 11\\q(-1)=20\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}f(1) &= -11\\f(-2)&=20\end{aligned}\qquad\text{while $q$ satisfies}\qquad\begin{aligned}q(1) &= 11\\q(-1)&=20\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

The result is

[image: aligned equations]

Edit : (A comment about mbox) To include text within an equation, you are better off to use the `\text` command rather than the `\mbox.`

Answer (score 1):

I would say as a good solution the use of the array environment within the align environment:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{l}
f(1) = -11\\
f(-2)
\end{array}
\qquad \text{while $q$ satisfies}
\qquad
\begin{array}{r}
q(1) = 11,\\
q(-1) = 20  
\end{array}
\end{align}
```